# Angular select, get another value as option when empty

Tags: angularjs

Here is my code:

```
<select id="storeSelectBox" ng-model="model.store" ng-options="store.name for store in model.stores[model.retailer.shortName]" ng-change="retailerSelected()"></select>
```

My issue is following: since 'store.name' is not mandatory it can be emtpy and select shows empty items. Is there any possibility to get 'store.shortName' only when 'store.name' is empty? Would be great to modify somehow ng-options expression without touching controller.
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: show both then use ng-if to leverage showing only one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this,

```
<select id="storeSelectBox" ng-model="model.store" ng-change="retailerSelected()">
    <option ng-repeat="store in model.stores[model.retailer.shortName]" ng-value="store">
        <span ng-if="store.name">{{store.name}}</span>
        <span ng-if="!store.name">{{store.shortName}}</span>
    </option>
</select>
```

It will show shortName if name is empty, still entire store object will be assigned to `model.store`

Comment: It works partially. It shows items as expected, but when I will choose any option it's not shown in select as a choosen.

Comment: It should just work fine, you maybe changing the value of model.store in ng-change function